# How to change settings or unfollow a user whose account has been withheld for legal reasons in my country?

Tags: twitter

I am from Country C1 & I follow a user U1 who is from country C2.

User U1's account has been blocked on Twitter at a country level by my country. If I go to the user's profile, this is what I see:

[image: Withheld Account]

I don't see tweets by the user - which is fine. But I see retweets by the user but with the name of the retweeter withheld.

I want to do one of these things

- Unfollow the user
- Mute the user
- Not see retweets by the user

But all these are settings on the user's profile page & it's not accessible to me - so how do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a VPN to switch to a country that this user is not withheld in and then unfollow them.

Comment: Doesn't work. Tried it. The account has already been marked to a country. So temporary switching to VPN doesn't unwithhold the account.

Answer (score 0):

All you can do at this time is to individually Unfollow, Mute, Block each of the follower's accounts.

Directly from Twitter support, in their own words:

> Twitter’s account suggestions are based on algorithms that make
> personalized suggestions for you, this cannot be changed. We do
> apologize that there is no mechanism in place to mute or block
> Retweets from followers of withheld accounts without having to block
> or mute them individually when you see them come across your timeline.
>
> We want you to enjoy Twitter, so we have a lot of different tools you
> can use to control your experience.
>
> Tap the (three dot) icon at the top of any Tweet, right from your Home
> timeline, to quickly access options like unfollow, mute, block,
> report, and more.
>
> Control what you see:
>
> Unfollow: Easiest way to stop seeing someone’s Tweets on your Home
> timeline
>
> Mute: You won’t see that account's Tweets in your timeline, but you’ll
> still follow them
>
> Block: Restrict the account’s ability to interact with your account
>
> Report: You can report an account you think is spam, abusive, posting
> sensitive media, impersonating someone else, among other violations

Don't shoot me, I'm only the messenger.